# how to set ListView item height

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have a ListActivity which i want to change Item height refer to device height

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
            .
            .
            .
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mainMenuItems));
}
```

its my ListActivity on galaxy nexus S :

[image]

and on galaxy nexus 7 :
[image]

how should I define listview items height ???

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `ListView` items height are the height of item layout contents, eg `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` height. If you want different height, create an xml file and put a `android:layout_height` or `android:minHeight` attribute.

This is a modified `simple_list_item_1` which refers to your value

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/your_defined_minumum_height"/>
```

and in your dimen.xml

```
<dimen name="your_defined_minumum_height">48dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ListView lvLogs = new ListView(this);
lvLogs.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, logs) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
            textView.setMinHeight(0); // Min Height
            textView.setMinimumHeight(0); // Min Height 
            textView.setHeight(44); // Height
            return view;
        }
    });
```

**Note: MinHeight and MinimumHeight is required!!!**

Set the minimum height to 0~20(or higher) : `setMinHeight(?)` + `setMinimumHeight(?)`

Then the TextView in ListView will have a normal height (smaller than the ListView's default)

If you want to specific the height in pixel, then use `setHeight(?)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own custom layout file for each item in ListView. There you can edit whatever you want, and you can get a lot of benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Customise an adapter for your `ListView` with the information of screenHeight (H). Given that you want your screen to show 9 columns (items), you can specify the height of each of them as H/9. By doing so, you can precisely control the appearance of your `ListView` on all devices.